# Capturing graql apollo query execution time in query result

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, appinsights

I have been trying to capture graphql http query execution time in the query result. I found a solution to use "apollo-link-logger" but this will only log it to console and does not attach it to the query resultgs.

What I am trying is I need to log all the queries of my frontend app in Azure Application Insights, unfortunately graphql http requests are not automatically captured by App Insights and so I am creating custom events for the same, where I was to log the query name, execution time, success or failure.